# Changing my domain name - need a checklist

Tags: seo, domains, branding

I have a web site currently with say 'a.com', with a quite good Google rankings and a hit rate. Now due to some change in business needs I need to change my domain name to 'b.com'.

1. Can you provide me with a check list of all points I need to consider before going up with new name.
2. How can I minimize the effect on my SEO rankings? Can I carry forward existing rank to new domain.

Comment: What you are asking is a lot. A precise checklist? How are we even able to provide that not knowing what you do, etc.? Basically, you need to make sure that ALL links ever created to a.com will be forwarded with a 301 redirect to b.com. Then make sure you are not missing out on your email-addresses, signups to services, login information, etc. Make sure you add new email addresses to each service, since some will send a verification email to the old address, etc. etc.

Comment: Hey @DKOATED, Thanks man, M just looking for general steps to make sure not to miss a silly point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the point **1 - check list**: I would install a copy of the site in the new domain in a new different server (if possible) and debug by comparing. Don't forget to check image sources, as your new site can still get images from the old domain. Don't make the new domain/site public until all bugs have been fixed, as having both online at the same time can penalize the new domain, that will be considered duplicate content by search engines.

As for **point 2 - SEO**: 301 redirects for the old domain (at least in the next **months** after the migration, but you should try to have them as long as possible), should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

SEOMoz has a pretty good checklist:

http://www.seomoz.org/blog/seo-guide-how-to-properly-move-domains